# Como setar um ReturnPath no envio de email SMTP

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, smtp

Estou fazendo um console que envie e-mails.

Preciso que os e-mails enviados com erro retornem para um outro e-mail (diferente do que enviou).

Consegui setar o `ReturnPath` no *header* do e-mail, mas não funcionou.

Estou usando a biblioteca: `System.Net.Mail`.

Criação da minha mensagem de e-mail:

[image: código]

Reparem que o `Return-Path` mudou, e é diferente do e-mail que enviou.

[image: resultado]

E-mail que enviou:

[image: resultado]

Tentei colocar direto no *header*, mas aí o `Return-Path` nem muda.

```
mail.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "errorsTeste@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve adicionar um *header* correto na mensagem, algo assim:

```
mail.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "endereco@abc.com");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/MailSenders.cs).

O `Sender` não é isto, na verdade ele é o `From`.

Comment: Então... Tentei usar isso já, mas, desse jeito ele não muda nem nos detalhes da mensagem...

Ai pesquisei um pouco, e vi algumas pessoas falando para usar o Sender, com isso ele ate muda o ReturnPath, mas nao me retorna as mensagens

Comment: Mas é a única forma, pode ser que está fazendo algo errado que está afetando.